# How do you upgrade a library on a buildroot system?

Tags: upgrade, buildroot, dnp3

I am very new to embedded Linux and am working with buildroot. We have a DNP3 library that is very old and would like to upgrade from 2.3 to 3.1. I do not know where to even start.
Can someone point me to a tutorial or instructions on how to upgrade an existing library or package?

Answer (score 1):

It's not explained explicitly in the Buildroot manual, but updating a package is:

- finding the package directory (e.g. `package/dnp3`);
- change the version number in the `dnp3.mk` file;
- download the package with `make dnp3-source`;
- this will give an error because of a missing hash: note the hash and update it in `dnp3.hash`.

Of course, often that is not enough because the updated package has new dependencies, or it has to be patched to be able to build it in cross-compilation, or various other issues.